# Creating BBCode style of tags into my custom blog

Tags: php, html, bbcode

I want to create BBCode kind of tags for my custom Blog system. However I have no Idea where to start from. I'm not asking for the full working script or anything (if it's a long code whitch it probably is), but I want to know what do I need and some basic leads to get me going. Thanks for all the hints!

This is the code that I'm wanting to add it to:

```
    $query=$db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, LEFT(body, 400) AS body, category FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=posts.category_id ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body, $category);    
while($query->fetch()):
        $lastspace = strrpos($body, ' ');?>
    <article>
    <div class="5pxPadding">
    <h2><?php echo "<a href='post.php?id=$post_id'>$title</a>";?></h2>
    <?php echo "Category: ", $category;?>
    <?php echo "<br><br>";?>
    <p><?php
//END BBCODE, ECHO POST
    $body_sub = substr($body, 0) . "<br><br><a href='post.php?id=$post_id'> Continue Reading →</a>";
    echo nl2br($body_sub); ?></p>
    <?php echo "<hr>" ; ?>
    </div>
</article>
```

I know the code is messy btw, you don't need to tell me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do it kind of like this:

```
$str = 'this is a string with [bold]bold[/bold] text';
$str = preg_replace('/(\[bold\])/', '<strong>', $str );
$str = preg_replace('/(\[\/bold\])/', '</strong>', $str );
echo $str;
```

I'm not great at regex, so I'm sure some wizard can combine my two statements into one, but this is the general idea. Just replace any bbcode with the proper html?

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vkMMQt)**

Comment: yeah, Im a beginner, should read up on preg a little more. Thanks.

Comment: Hi again, Where do I need to add the codes? I've added a snippet of what I'm trying to add it to, no success so far.